Java.Lang.IllegalStateException-java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallIntMethod(JniObjectReference , JniMethodInfo , JniArgumentValue* )

Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractInt32Method(String , IJavaPeerable , JniArgumentValue* )

AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentTransactionInvoker.Commit()

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ModalNavigationManager.ModalContainer.Destroy()

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ModalNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<PopModalAsync>b__0(Animator a)

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.GenericAnimatorListener.OnAnimationEnd(Animator animation)

Android.Animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter.n_OnAnimationEnd_Landroid_animation_Animator_(IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr )

Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(_JniMarshal_PPL_V , IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr )

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(SourceFile:38)

androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(SourceFile:73)

androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(Unknown Source:1)

crc64338477404e88479c.GenericAnimatorListener.n_onAnimationEnd(Native Method)

crc64338477404e88479c.GenericAnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Unknown Source:0)

android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationEnd ViewPropertyAnimator.java:1119

android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd Animator.java:608

android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation ValueAnimator.java:1333

android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame ValueAnimator.java:1588

android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame AnimationHandler.java:307

android.animation.AnimationHandler.-$$Nest$mdoAnimationFrame(Unknown Source:0)

android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame AnimationHandler.java:86

android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run Choreographer.java:1403

android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run Choreographer.java:1413

android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks Choreographer.java:1040

android.view.Choreographer.doFrame Choreographer.java:920

android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run Choreographer.java:1388

android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:942

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:99

android.os.Looper.loopOnce Looper.java:240

android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:351

android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:8423

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:584

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:1013


Please solution of above issue

Can you show the code that causes this issue? What are you trying to do?

there is found any root couse issue, log in appcenteronly

Did you use a debugger?

No @PMF, just tried dubug manule to reproduce issue but not replicate yet.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
